# Triggering asynchronous events sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several events, that are asynchronous, as they involve ajax calls, like this

```
$base.on('submit', '.form', function(){
    $.ajax({url: this.action, data: $(this).serialize(), type: 'POST'}).done(function(response){
        $("#container").append(response);
    });
    return false;    
});

$base.on("click", "#addNew", function(){
    $("#editArea").load($(this).data('href'));
    return false;
});
```

What i want to achieve is to synchronously trigger first `form.submit()` event, and only after it finishes trigger `$("#addNew").click()` event, and then do something else. I tried something like:

```
$.when($form.trigger('submit'))
    .then(function(){$new.trigger('click')})
    .done(function(){
        //do something
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Also, i must note, i can't use `triggerHandler` as these events are delegated (they fire on ajax-inserted content).
Of course, i could make these ajax calls synchronous via `async: true` but i'd like to avoid modifying existing code as much as possible. Is there any other way to do such things?

Comment: Dowvote without a comment is no-go.

Comment: Dear, is it normal the string `$('#container")` begin with ' and finish with " ?

Comment: It's not, but it's not my proper code either (i write in coffeeScript), i wrote it by hand, so i made some typos along the way.

Comment: Why write promise-pyramids, promises allow you to keep your code rather linear?

Comment: try use $.when.then instead of .done

Comment: @daremachine: tested, but no difference between these two.

Comment: You probably mean "sequentially", not "synchronously"? Regardless, you cannot do that, because event triggering does not have a return value. Instead of triggering events, you rather should call those async function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it'd be difficult and nasty if you wanted to do this without changing the existing `submit` and `click` event handlers. Those AJAX requests are *side effects* of those event handlers, so you'd have to somehow monitor and modify outgoing AJAX requests to hook in your extra handling. Or perhaps you could monitor `#container` and `#editArea` for DOM changes...

The simplest solution would be to extract those event handlers as separate functions and have them return a promise. That way, the caller can hook up these promises anyway they like.

```
function submitForm($form){
    return $.ajax({url: $form.prop('action'), data: $form.serialize(), type: 'POST'})
        .then(function(response){
            $("#container").append(response);
        });
});

function addNew($new){
    // Note: using $.get and $.html instead, since $.load doesn't return a promise
    return $.get($new.data('href'))
        .then(function(response){
            $("#editArea").html(response);
        });
});
```

In your event handler, you can simply ignore the returned promise.

```
$base.on('submit', '.form', function(){
    submitForm($(this));
});

$base.on("click", "#addNew", function(){
    addNew($(this));
});
```

For your sequence however, you can then chain the returned promises.

```
submitForm($form)
    .then(function(){addNew($new)})
    .then(function(){
        //do something
    });
```

Comment: This method worked just fine, thank you. Also, this gave me a perfect excuse to refactor this code into several `CoffeeScript` classes, which made it a lot better as a pleasant bonus (: